# How to import directives in a nestJS graphQLModule?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I need to generate typeScript types for mongoDB using `graphql-code-generator` and the `typescript-mongodb` plugin, but I don't understand how to import the directives of that plugin in a nestJS application.

In my backend app (nestJS) the graphql module is defined like this:

```
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql']
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In the [docs](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/plugins/typescript-mongodb#usage-example) of the plugin I see I have to use the directives:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema'
import { DIRECTIVES } from '@graphql-codegen/typescript-mongodb'

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: [
    DIRECTIVES
    // the rest of your GraphQL types
  ],
  resolvers
})
```

But I don't get it how to implement this in my nestJS app, which is using `GraphQLModule`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install these packages to the current nestjs repo

```
npm i @graphql-codegen/cli @graphql-codegen/typescript-mongodb
```

2. add codegen config file `codegen.yml`

```
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:3000/graphql"
documents: null
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-mongodb"
```

The above code schema should point to the local GraphQl endpoint. The above code will generate types in `src/generated/graphql.ts` file

3. add generate script in your package.json scripts

```
    "generate": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml"
```

4. run generate script

```
npm run generate
```

Note: graphQL server (`start:dev`) should be running while using generate command

Working repo link - https://github.com/vinodsai-a/nestjs-graphql-codegen-example

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This far I had already setup the apps. But you did not write anything about the graphql implementation (GraphQLModule) and on that part the directives are missing in my app. The generation of the types is not the problem.

Comment: You implemented `upperDirectiveTransformer` in your repo, but how do I implement the directives of `graphql-codegen/typescript-mongodb`?